# Determine the convergence of the following improper integrals of non-negative integrands:

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

---

### $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{ \sqrt{sin(3x)}}{x\left(e^{3\sqrt{x}}-1)\right)}dx$

---

I know

### $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{ \sqrt{sin(3x)}}{x\left(e^{3\sqrt{x}}-1)\right)}dx = \lim_{c\to 0}\int_{c}^{\pi}\frac{ \sqrt{sin(3x)}}{x\left(e^{3\sqrt{x}}-1)\right)}dx$

I think it needs to be a comparison test but do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

When $x\approx 0$ you have
$$
\sqrt{\sin 3x}=\sqrt{3x}+o(\sqrt x),\quad x\to 0
$$
and
$$
x(e^{3\sqrt x}-1)=3x\sqrt{x}+o(x^{3/2}),\quad x\to 0
$$
Therefore, the integrand is
$$
f(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt{3}x}+...
$$
and the integral is divergent.

You can also use “limit comparison” with $g(x)=1/x$.